# Is there a way to make an SPFx custom webpart to occupy the whole real estate?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, spfx

I have been using SharePoint Online (**SPO 2016**) and SPFx for a while now but up until recently there is something happening with the Full-width web parts, they appear squeezed to the center of the page. An example is shown:
[image]

On the code, I have added the option to support full bleed to true. Everything configured properly but upon inspection on the browser dev tools, I found out that a certain class with the name **f_b_50a7110f** had a property of margin: auto, now to fix the issue I added on my code the same class and gave it a width of 100%. `.f_b_50a7110f {width: 100%;}`.

[image]

This solves the issue temporarily but the problem is that the name of the class changes from time to time. For instance, at the time of asking this, it is called **p_i_50a7110f** thus the solution does not stick. Has anyone encountered the same issue? And what was the solution? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks. Here is my package.json file.

```js
{
  "name": "homepage-global",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp bundle",
    "clean": "gulp clean",
    "test": "gulp test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "1.11.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "1.11.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "1.11.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-property-pane": "1.11.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "1.11.0",
    "@pnp/sp": "^2.1.1",
    "@pnp/spfx-controls-react": "2.4.0",
    "materialize-css": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "office-ui-fabric-react": "6.214.0",
    "react": "16.8.5",
    "react-dom": "16.8.5",
    "react-materialize": "^3.9.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.3": "0.3.5",
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "1.11.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "1.11.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-tslint-rules": "1.11.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench": "1.11.0",
    "@types/chai": "3.4.34",
    "@types/es6-promise": "0.0.33",
    "@types/mocha": "2.2.38",
    "@types/react": "16.8.8",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.8.3",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.1",
    "ajv": "~5.2.2",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "gulp": "~3.9.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, SharePoint Framework client-side web parts can't be placed in full-width column layouts. To allow users to add your web part to full-width columns, in the web part manifest (the ***.manifest.json** file next to the web part *.ts file) set the **supportsFullBleed** property to **true**.

```
{
  //...

  "requiresCustomScript": false,
  "supportsFullBleed": true,

  "preconfiguredEntries": [{
    //...
  }]
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/basics/use-web-parts-full-width-column

You could also use an extension:

```
import { override } from '@microsoft/decorators';
import { BaseApplicationCustomizer } from '@microsoft/sp-application-base';
export interface ISiteFullWidthApplicationCustomizerProperties {
  message: string;
}

require("./css/custom.module.scss");

export default class SiteFullWidthApplicationCustomizer extends BaseApplicationCustomizer<ISiteFullWidthApplicationCustomizerProperties> {

  @override
  public onInit(): Promise<void> {
    if (typeof (Event) === 'function') {
      window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
    }
    else {
      var resizeEvent = window.document.createEvent('UIEvents');
      resizeEvent.initUIEvent('resize', true, false, window, 0);
      window.dispatchEvent(resizeEvent);
    }

    return Promise.resolve();
  }
}
```

custom.module.scss:

```
:global {
 .sp-pageLayout-sideNav [class^='deferredLeftNav'] {
    max-width: 0px;
  }

  .sp-pageLayout-sideNav .SPCanvas-canvas  {
    max-width: 100%;
  }

  .sp-pageLayout-sideNav .CanvasZoneContainer:first-child .CanvasZone.row {
    max-width: 100%;
  }

  .sp-pageLayout-sideNav .CanvasZoneContainer:first-child .CanvasZone.row,
  .sp-pageLayout-sideNav .CanvasZoneContainer:first-child .CanvasZone.row .CanvasSection,
  .sp-pageLayout-sideNav .CanvasZoneContainer:first-child .CanvasZone.row .CanvasSection .ControlZone,
  {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }

  .sp-pageLayout-sideNav .CanvasZone.row.CanvasZone--alignment.CanvasZone--read.CanvasZone--noMargin {
    margin: auto;
  }

  .sp-pageLayout-sideNav [class^='spInnerCommentsWrapper_'] {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I would mention I created a chrome extension that removed max-width restrictions and makes the workbench 1920px width, with scaling down working as well.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/spfx-workbench-manager/gnchlhbjhljidedhighhkgbfchmejlcp